# SQL query that runs a new SQL query for the same row based on a return condition

Tags: sql, db2

I'm having trouble formulating this problem, and it is perhaps best explained through code.

I'm writing a query that only returns rows that has a specific priority. For each row it returns with that priority, it should also run a new query, but with a different priority this time (the second query may not return any rows). The final result is the combined results from both queries.

So, the code I have now looks like this:

```sql
SELECT I.ItemNumber, I.FromLocation, I.ToLocation
FROM ItemLocation AS I
INNER JOIN Delivery AS D
    ON I.ItemNumber = D.ItemNumber
    AND I.FromLocation = D.FromLocation
    AND I.ToLocation = D.ToLocation
WHERE I.Priority IN ('A', 'C')
    AND D.DeliveryStart > 20191001
```

The problem with this query is that I only want the ItemNumbers with priority `'C'` *if* there were any ItemNumbers with priority `'A'`. Now I get all of them regardless. And If `'A'` *doesn't* return any rows, it should do the same query, but replace Priority `'A'` with `'B'`, so that the new (but still erroneous) `WHERE` clause will be:

```
WHERE I.Priority IN ('B', 'C')
```

I have tried handling this logic in code, but this approach will require multiple queries, which unfortunately reduces the performance dramatically.

Is there any way of doing this *in* the SQL query?

Comment: Problems that are difficult to explain are usually better explained using *data* not *code*.

Comment: Do you need this rule inside each `ItemNumber` or for any Item Numbers? I.e. what’s the expected result for `(ItemNumber, Priority) = (1, ‘A’), (2, ‘C’)`?

Comment: @MarkBarinstein I need the rule inside each ```ItemNumber```, yes, and each ```ItemNumber``` may have two out of these three priorities (either ```'A'``` + ```'C'``` or ```'B'``` + ```'C'```)

Answer (score 0):

Consider an `LEFT JOIN` + `UNION` of subqueries or CTEs per your written need:

> I only want the ItemNumbers with priority 'C' if there were any ItemNumbers with priority 'A'...And If 'A' doesn't return any rows, it should do the same query, but replace Priority 'A' with 'B'

```
WITH A_records AS (
   SELECT I.ItemNumber, I.FromLocation, I.ToLocation
   FROM ItemLocation AS I
   INNER JOIN Delivery AS D
      ON I.ItemNumber = D.ItemNumber
      AND I.FromLocation = D.FromLocation
      AND I.ToLocation = D.ToLocation
   WHERE I.Priority = 'A'
     AND D.DeliveryStart > 20191001
), B_records AS (
   SELECT I.ItemNumber, I.FromLocation, I.ToLocation
   FROM ItemLocation AS I
   INNER JOIN Delivery AS D
      ON I.ItemNumber = D.ItemNumber
      AND I.FromLocation = D.FromLocation
      AND I.ToLocation = D.ToLocation
   WHERE I.Priority = 'B'
     AND D.DeliveryStart > 20191001
), C_records AS (
   SELECT I.ItemNumber, I.FromLocation, I.ToLocation
   FROM ItemLocation AS I
   INNER JOIN Delivery AS D
      ON I.ItemNumber = D.ItemNumber
      AND I.FromLocation = D.FromLocation
      AND I.ToLocation = D.ToLocation
   WHERE I.Priority = 'C'
     AND D.DeliveryStart > 20191001
)

SELECT a.ItemNumber as A_ItemNumber, a.FromLocation As A_FromLocation,
       a.ToLocation As A_ToLocation,
       c.ItemNumber as C_ItemNumber, c.FromLocation As C_FromLocation, 
       c.ToLocation As C_ToLocation
FROM A_records a
LEFT JOIN C_records c
  ON a.ItemNumber = c.ItemNumber

UNION ALL

SELECT B.ItemNumber as B_ItemNumber, B.FromLocation As B_FromLocation,
       B.ToLocation As B_ToLocation,
       c.ItemNumber as C_ItemNumber, c.FromLocation As C_FromLocation, 
       c.ToLocation As C_ToLocation
FROM B_records b
LEFT JOIN C_records c
  ON b.ItemNumber = c.ItemNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH TAB (ItemNumber, Priority) AS 
(
VALUES
  (1, 'A')
, (1, 'C')
, (1, 'D')

, (2, 'B')
, (2, 'C')

, (3, 'A')
, (3, 'B')
, (3, 'C')

, (4, 'C')
)
SELECT ItemNumber, Priority
FROM 
(
SELECT 
  ItemNumber, Priority
, COUNT(CASE Priority WHEN 'A' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemNumber) COUNT_A
, COUNT(CASE Priority WHEN 'B' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemNumber) COUNT_B
FROM TAB
WHERE Priority IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
)
WHERE 
   Priority = 'A'
OR Priority = 'B' AND COUNT_A = 0
OR Priority = 'C' AND COUNT_A + COUNT_B > 0
;

|ITEMNUMBER |PRIORITY|
|-----------|--------|
|1          |A       |
|1          |C       |
|2          |B       |
|2          |C       |
|3          |A       |
|3          |C       |
```

We use OLAP function `COUNT` to get a number of records with the corresponding `Priority` in the same `ItemNumber` group for each record.
If it's not the expected result, then provide it on these sample data above.